# Insert events to get desired state before running behaviour tests

Tags: java, testing, akka, akka-persistence

I am trying to insert events before I try to execute some commands. I want to get my behaviour in a state ready for particular test, without needing to rerun all the commands, like database fixtures in regular testing.

I am using:

```
akka.persistence.testkit.javadsl.EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit`
akka.actor.testkit.typed.javadsl.ActorTestKit`
akka.persistence.testkit.javadsl.PersistenceTestKit
```

I create my test kits:

```
static final ActorTestKit testKit = ActorTestKit.create(EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit.config());

static final EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit<Command, Event, State> eventSourcedTestKit = EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit.create(
    testKit.system(),
    MyPersistentBehaviour.create(),
    EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit.disabledSerializationSettings()
);
```

and then I try to do:

```
eventSourcedTestKit.persistenceTestKit().persistForRecovery(
    "1",
    //List of my akka events
);
eventSourcedTestKit.restart();
```

but as soon as I try to `runCommand` those events I persisted aren't applied.

Is this even a good way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I passed `"1"` as persistenceId when I invoked `persistForRecovery` and that is wrong, persistenceId is a composite of entity name + id, so it would look like `"order|1"`.